# How to automate the failover in SQL Sever Agent Jobs with "Always On"

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, database-administration

I am running SQL Server Agent Jobs in SQL Server 2014, It has "Always On" enabled.

Primary server: A
Secondary Server: B

We faced a situation, Server A had a network issue so "Always on" feature automatically switched the primary server to B.
In this case, our jobs are running in Server A so it has been failed since the Server A goes to read only mode.

Is there a way to automate the SQL Server Agent Jobs without any manual intervention using "Always on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the jobs on both instances, your primary and secondary replica and then use `sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica` in the first step of your job.

```
IF sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica ( 'yourDBname' ) <> 1   
   BEGIN  
      -- raiserror, so the job step fails and the entire job fails
      -- sometimes you may want to set this job to "finish with success" when this step fails
      -- so that you don't get alerts
      declare @errMsg varchar(600) = 'This is meant to run on the primary replica'
      raiserror(@errMsg,16,1)
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN  
      print 'This is the primary replica, continue with the job'
   END
```

That would work for 2014+. For 2012 you can check some sys views for the first step.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT
               AGC.name -- Availability Group
             , RCS.replica_server_name -- SQL cluster node name
             , ARS.role_desc  -- Replica Role
             , AGL.dns_name  -- Listener Name
            FROM
            sys.availability_groups_cluster AS AGC
                LEFT JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states AS RCS
                ON RCS.group_id = AGC.group_id
                LEFT JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS ARS
                ON ARS.replica_id = RCS.replica_id
                LEFT JOIN sys.availability_group_listeners AS AGL
                ON AGL.group_id = ARS.group_id
            WHERE
              RCS.replica_server_name = @@SERVERNAME
              and ARS.role_desc = 'PRIMARY')

BEGIN
    print 'Continue with job'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        declare @errMsg varchar(600) = 'This is meant to run on the primary replica'
        raiserror(@errMsg,16,1)
END
```

Comment: I will vote up for your answer. This is good approach but can you tell me what should I do in the else part. If the automatic switch occurs then obviously it goes to else part. I don't want to run two sets of jobs ie., one in primary and other in secondary.

Comment: @StackUser i added an error message. If you add this to step 1 of your jobs, it should work fine. Then, when a failover happens, it will still only run on the primary replica.